# ADF, JDeveloper IDE, hangs everytime when I go to Application Module

Tags: tortoisesvn, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

My JDeveloper IDE hangs every time I go to `Application Module > Data Model` tab. I have tried re-installing. We’re using SVN Subversion for Server. We’re not able to process further because of this issue.

**It was working until I did commit on Subversion,** after that I'm facing this issue. My whole team is having this issue. Any help?

Comment: Please add JDeveloper version info and OS info. Do you see any error in OS logs? "It was working until I did commit on Subversion" - have you tried to revert that commit using TortoiseSVN?

Comment: are there too many instances of ViewObjects? did you think it is taking too much memory to load these?

Comment: Could you try to create a new test Application module with just one instance of a VO and try to open the data Model and see if it the issue is persisting?

Comment: What is the RAM capacity of your computer? also how much memory is allocated to jdeveloper? this info can be found at jdev.conf file / ide.conf file

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions:

1. Try to revert your SVN changes that caused the problem. Use Tortoise SVN for reverting changes, not Jdeveloper SVN client.
2. Try not to use Jdeveloper SVN client. You can use TortoiseSVN instead, as separate tool.
3. Additionally, I would try to disable all Jdeveloper Audit Rules. Go to: Preferences -> Audit -> Profiles -> Code Assist Rules", then uncheck "Application Development Framework". Restart Jdeveloper and see if you have problem anymore. If this works, try to enable each extension one by one and see if you can nail the one causing the problems.